# RFM Score for Customers for each day

Tags: sql, date

I am about to count so called RFM Score for our customers. Im using the rank function and sorting the customers to predefined clusters. 
What is the way to achieve RFM Score for all customers for all days? 
for e.x.

Customer Date RFM

Cust1        01.01.2013    xxx

Cust1        02.01.2013    xyx

...

Cust2        01.01.2013    yzx

...
etc.

Right now what I am doing I have a result based on current date (or state of the database). So for all customers an RFM Score of today only.

Any ideas?

Thanks and cheers,
Mats

Comment: Am I missing something? You want to count the RFM scores and are using a rank!? On first glance I'd say, you shoul use something like "SELECT Customer, COUNT DISTINCT(RFM) FROM ... GROUP BY Customer"

Comment: Its not relevant how do I count it. Just imagine a preferable KPI there instead of RFM. The question was how to count it for each day...not only for today.

Comment: In this case it should be sufficient to use something like SELECT Customer, Date, ["sum" or "count" or whatever KPI you need] FROM [table] GROUP BY Customer, Date

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the number of RFM's for each date, independent of customer:

```
SELECT DATE, COUNT(RFM) AS RFM
    FROM Table 
GROUP BY DATE
ORDER BY DATE
```

If you need to see the the number of RFM's for each date *for each customer*:

```
SELECT  CUSTOMER, DATE, COUNT(RFM) AS RFM
    FROM Table 
GROUP BY CUSTOMER, DATE
ORDER BY CUSTOMER, DATE
```

Comment: This would count the RFM per day per customer. However, I need a calculation of RFM per Customer per time period. For instance: Customer 1, period: from 2014 until date. Similarly per each date.

Comment: Can you give me some example data of what it looks like (more than just 3 rows) and what you need it to be?  That would really help me understand what you need.  Also, how do you know what the period is?  Is it a monthly period?  Is it a year period?  Is it from the beginning of time to the date in the row?

Comment: Exactly. For each Customer and each date I must count the RFM KPI. Each date means: period from the beginning of our data (2014) until the date. For instance: Customer 1 ...Date .....Period (2014-01-01 - date) ...RFM

Comment: Can you please provide some better examples of data? Like an extra 6 or 7 rows, then show me what you want that data to look like? That would be extremely helpful.